# German equivalent of "to tend to take on sth"

Tags: english-to-german

I would like to know how to express "to tend take on sth" How could I make better my following tranlation attempt or is it completely wrong?

> Most language teachers currently tend to take on the eclectic approach to language teaching partly.
>
> Die meisten Sprachlehrer übernehmen/annehmen derzeit eher zum Teil/teilweise auf die eklektische Ansatz zur Sprachunterricht.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*To tend* can be translated as either *tendieren* or *neigen*:

> Die meisten Sprachlehrer tendieren/neigen dazu, einen eklektischen Ansatz für den Sprachenunterricht zu verfolgen.

Comment: How do you find my second attempt: "Sprachlehrer neigen das Übernehmen, um eklektischen Ansatz zum Sprachunterricht." was it work?

Comment: @Berg please don't extend questions ex post, especially not in comments if it's not directly related to the post you're commenting on.